# MobileFirst JSON output choking on services returning backslash characters

Tags: json, xslt, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

We are using a lot of HTTPAdapaters in MobileFirst 6.3 calling SOAP services and translating to JSON via xslt transforms. We are seeing issues with backslash characters "\" appearing in the SOAP response and then getting placed as-is in the JSON output. Per rfc7159, backslashes should be escaped, either as \\ (double backslashes) or as as octal code.

What is the recommendation for dealing with this? Certainly we can write some XSLT that will do a replace in all fields, but not sure this is the best way.

Comment: This might happen due to IBM JSON that is used internally as the library. Can you add some more illustrative example of what is sent & how and the response you get in return?

Comment: Also consider perhaps to replace backslashes with '\\' before the JSON conversion. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Yeah we are currently replacing with \\ on the service layer, but was looking for something more robust. There are a handful of other characters that need to be escaped, according to the JSON spec, and I don't feel like we should be manually doing this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a workaround would be to replace backslashes with '\' before the JSON conversion.

I agree that the situation is not ideal and perhaps a more robust and spec-following library should used; please feel free to voice this concern via a feature request for a different library: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help